# Correctly Copying Worksheets When "Chart Data Range Too Complex"?

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2008

MS-Excel 2008 on OSX Mavericks. I don't think the problem is very version- or platform-specific.

1. Make a simple chart on a worksheet.
2. Make a copy of the worksheet.
3. Note the new chart in the new worksheet refers to the new worksheet, as it should.
4. Fiddle with the data so as to get the "Chart Data Range Too Complex" message in the "Select Data" dialog box. Just setting the data series name to a cell somewhere away from the data is enough to do it for me.
5. Make another copy of the worksheet.
6. Note that the newest chart in the newest worksheet *doesn't* refer to the newest worksheet.
7. Wail, gnash teeth, etc.

Imagine that making the "chart data range too complex" go away is not an option.

Any other workarounds?

Comment: I am sorry but I am having a hard time following you question.  Please consider revising it to: 
1) Improve the formatting
2) Change the time to be more specific on your problem

Good luck!

Comment: I can't reproduce this on MS-Excel 2011 OSX-Yosemite.  Can you be very specific about how you produce this (E.g. two columns with headers, scatter plot)

Comment: Enter "X" in cell A1

Enter "Y" in cell B1

Enter "1" in cell A2

Enter "2" in cell A3

Enter "3" in cell A4

Enter "4" in cell B2

Enter "5" in cell B3

Enter "6" in cell B4

Select cells A1:B4

Add an XY (Scatter) chart

Copy Worksheet to new worksheet

Note graph works properly

Return to first worksheet

Select chart

Right click, select data

Select "Name:"

Pick cell C7

Press OK

Copy Worksheet

Notice it doesn't work.

Comment: After entering multiple carriage returns in the above post, I notice the formatting has ignored them. Two carriage returns works in other fora; what works in this one?

Comment: I want to add a line break.  

Really I do.  

But two trailing spaces, <br/> or anything else seems to be ignored. <br>   
So who knows what it takes. I certainly don't. [br] This post was an experiment with every type of line break I can think of.

Comment: It turns out is *is* version-specific. Excel 2010 on Windows 7 64 Bit doesn't do it.